# Remove %20 from query inside hyperlink

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink, str-replace

I'm using:

```
header('Location: palette/'.urlencode(str_replace(' ','_',$title)));
```

To redirect a user upon submitting a form. This code above replaces `%20` (a space) with `_` for the title entered.

So instead of the user entering `"Great place"` and it trying to send them to a page called `palette/Great%20place` it sends them to `palette/Great_place`

Now my question, is it possible to apply this technique to a hyperlink?

I have the following loop:

```
<?php   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<a href='palette/$row[title]'><div id='main_col_container'>";
    echo "<div class='title'> $row[title]</div>";
    echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color1];'></div>";
    echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color2];'></div>";
    echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color3];'></div>";
    echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color4];'></div>";
    echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color5];'></div>";
    echo "</div></a>";
}
?>
```

The problem with this of course is, `$row[title]` represents the original data (it needs to show `"Great_place"`, not `"Great place"`

Just to clarify: **Is it possible to str_replace for a hyperlink for the purpose I'm after, if so, how can I go about this?**

---

EDIT: This is what I have got now which is working

```
<?php   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$titleurl   = str_replace(' ','_',$row['title']);

echo "<a href='palette/$titleurl'><div id='main_col_container'>";
echo "<div class='title'> $row[title]</div>";
echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color1];'></div>";
echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color2];'></div>";
echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color3];'></div>";
echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color4];'></div>";
echo "<div class='main_color' style='background: $row[color5];'></div>";
echo "</div></a>";
}
?>
```

Is this the best technique for the outcome? Or is it considered bad practise for whatever reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, just [concatenate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) your `str_replace` into the string instead of interpolating the variable.

Comment: That could work, or better yet: `$titleurl = str_replace(' ','_',$row['title']);`

Comment: ^ What I've just modified my coding to. Is this the best method do you think?

Comment: Well, personally I'd make the `color1` through `colour5` lines a loop, but other thatn that is seems okay.

Comment: Okay great, thank you Kolink. I've marked this as Answered. Thanks for the quick response